# Angular Material: Why is my sidenav only as tall as it's parent element?

Tags: angular-material

I have an `<md-toolbar>` directive that contains a `<md-button>`. When the button is clicked, I am triggering a `<md-sidenav>` to open. So far, things are working, but my `<md-sidenav>` seems to be only taking up the height of the `<md-toolbar>` it is contained within.

For example, my `<md-toolbar>` is 64px tall. So currently, the 
`<md-sidenav>` is only showing 64px tall.

Is there a way to make the `<md-sidenav>` render above everything regardless? I assume I can set a fixed height or figure out a fluid height later, but as for now no matter what I do, the `<md-sidenav>` is only taking up the height of it's parent element.

All other `<md-menu>` elements I have in my `<md-toolbar>` are working properly.

Here is the html template:

**messages.template.html**

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleMessages()" aria-label="Messages">
    <i class="material-icons">message</i>
</md-button>


<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">
    <md-toolbar>
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-padding>
        <p>This is the sidenav.</p>
        <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.close()" class="md-primary">
            Close this thing!
        </md-button>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

Here is my component that is listening to the click and triggering the `<md-sidenav>`:

**messages.component.js**

```
this.toggleMessages = function toggleMessages() {
    $mdSidenav('right').toggle().then(function () {
        //
    });
};

/**
 * Close the messages side nav.
 */
this.close = function () {
    $mdSidenav('right').toggle().then(function () {
        //
    });
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

[image]